# ios Swift 3 app crash in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken func

Tags: ios, swift3, notifications

**original question:**

my function looks like this. The problem is that it works on my device but not on others. I don't recognize what I did wrong

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Convert token to string
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})

    let preferences = UserDefaults.standard

    let savedtoken = preferences.string(forKey: "token")


    if(savedtoken != deviceTokenString)
    {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "myurl")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let session = URLSession.shared

        session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in
            print("Entered the completionHandler")
            }.resume()

        preferences.set(deviceTokenString, forKey: "token")
        let didSave = preferences.synchronize()
    }
}
```

**problem was:**

sorry guys such a stupid mistake :( in "myurl" I send *UIDevice.current.name* as a parameter. What I did not think of is that a device name could contain whitespaces. And because my own device has no whitespace in its name it work but on devices of others not. 
Very stupid of me but I will learn from it. thanks all

Comment: What is the exception message and which line does it crash on?

Comment: This line will return nil initially
**let savedtoken = preferences.string(forKey: "token")**
which can lead crash... initialize it with empty string

Answer (score 4):

You can save it every time. Dont check if it exists or not.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
        print(deviceTokenString)
        UserDefaults.standard.setObject(deviceTokenString, forKey: "device_token")
    }
```

Comment: **Never** use `setValue:forKey` with `UserDefaults` unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC. The dedicated method is `setObject:forKey`.

Comment: Yes, you should. And `synchronize()` isn't needed either in this case. The framework updates the database periodically.

Comment: I suggest to use synchronize() on ever write operation on userdefault to make sure your changes has been saved.

Comment: no need of `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` , it increase the memory and time also